xy coordinates of aligned icons in the center of the width
I have an area of total width 1920 (can be different) and I need to evenly spread the icons based on xy in the given width (the height doesn't matter), the elements should always be aligned in the center of the page (and in the center of each column, if we can call them like that).
If for example the length is 1 should go in the center, 2 in the middle of each column, the sum of the elements per row should always be 8 (or more could be a variable).
count = 0
width = 1920
length = self.get_length(elements["icon"])
for item in elements["icon"]
    count += 1
    x = (self.get_length / 8) *((count % 8) - 0.5)
    if count > 8:
        x = (width / 8) *((count % 8) - 0.5)
    if count % 8 = 0
        y += 20



What exactly is your question? It seems you already have the necessary ideas.
